# How to read recurring events in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: javascript, calendar, sharepoint-hosted-app, recurring-events

would like to know how to get the recurring events for SharePoint calendar from SharePoint hosted app. There is an option to get normally using SPServices. But problem is we cannot use SPServices in SharePoint hosted app. I am stucking at below points:

1. For weekly events which are recurring for every 2 or 3 weeks on specified weekdays like Sunday, monday etc.
2. In above scenario how to calculate every 2 or 3 weeks dates based on starting event date.

I am using to get the recurrence data as following. It is giving me in xml string. based on that I am planning do calculations. I am able to successfully populate data for daily recurring events. But weekly it is problematic. monthly i haven't started yet.

```
appWebUrl +"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/RecurrenceData?@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'",
```

I am getting data as below

```
<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>su</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><weekly su="TRUE" mo="TRUE" tu="TRUE" we="TRUE" weekFrequency="1" /></repeat><repeatInstances>10</repeatInstances></rule></recurrence>
```

Now how to extract the dates based on above xml string?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no way to get the Recurring data using this endpoint because all it does is returns a XML schema. All you can do is use this schema and build your own logic to calculate date. you ca follow this [blog](https://fatalfrenchy.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/sharepoint-recurrence-data-schema/) for understanding different schema returned for different events.

This concerned is already being raise through [user voice 1](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15147117-provide-csom-and-rest-api-for-recurring-calendar-e) and [user voice 2](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/9065308-add-support-for-recurring-events-in-the-rest-api)

The only [workaround](http://www.rapidcircle.com/inconvenient-recurrence-data-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-using-client-om-js/) we have right now is to use old vti_bin/list.asmx API
also refer this [blog](https://coder87.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/get-calendar-recurrent-events-by-csom-in-sharepoint-2013/) for clear implementation of list.asmx API

Comment: You are right, still not supported currently....

Comment: But is it possible to call list.asmx from SharePoint app?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You have to write code into SharePoint